# PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Cannot get the reflection object

Tags: c#, dll, postsharp, autocad-plugin

I am developing an autocad plugin and I am using PostSharp OnMethodBoundaryAspect to do some tasks before each command introduced by the plugin. I have added the aspect declaratively using attributes.

```
[PSerializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Public)]
public class OnCommandBoundaryAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect {
    ...

}
```

and then in the command class

```
[OnCommandBoundaryAspect]
public class AnnotationCommands {

    [CommandMethod("MY_ACAD_COMMAND")]
    public void MyCommand() {
        doStuff();
    }

}
```

Everything works fine when compiling the plugin against normal acad dlls(the dlls coming with an ordinary autocad installation). We also have autocad OEM product where the plugin is included. Now when compiling the plugin with the autocad OEM dlls, I get **PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException**, see stack

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unhandled exception (postsharp-net40-x64-srv.exe release | .NET Framework 4.7): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Cannot get the reflection object for 'Acdbmgd.dll'.**
   at ^Mzw3\.bgGgRlJ.^cCM832sT[??0](Object _0, BindingOptions _1, ^d1u4kZd5aJLe _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.^Q77Ni+3v(AssemblyEnvelope _0, BindingOptions _1)
   at ^XJbqCOExOmCj.^NRQTI+sj(INamedType _0, BindingOptions _1)
   at ^Mzw3\.bgGgRlJ.^cCM832sT[??0](Object _0, BindingOptions _1, ^d1u4kZd5aJLe _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.GetSystemType(Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments, BindingOptions options)
   at ^XJbqCOExOmCj.^6pB/qWH+(IMethod _0, Type& _1, Type[] _2, Type[] _3, Type[] _4, BindingOptions _5)
   at ^XJbqCOExOmCj.^4IrPP9eT(Object _0, IMethod _1, Type[] _2, Type[] _3, BindingOptions _4)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodDefDeclaration.^NqB3CEvX(BindingOptions _0)
   at ^Mzw3\.bgGgRlJ.^cCM832sT[??0](Object _0, BindingOptions _1, ^d1u4kZd5aJLe _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodDefDeclaration.GetSystemMethod(Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeaverInstance..ctor(AspectWeaver aspectWeaver, AspectInstanceInfo aspectInstanceInfo)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeavers.MethodLevelAspectWeaverInstance..ctor(MethodLevelAspectWeaver aspectWeaver, AspectInstanceInfo aspectInstanceInfo)
   at ^wy1eTA/ccvw/.CreateAspectWeaverInstance(AspectInstanceInfo _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeaverTask.^lp9i7ZhC(InstructionWriter _0, AspectInstanceInfo _1, StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1 _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeaverTask.^gJhZb6Cg.^KzeTZ0pV(IMetadataDeclaration _0, AspectInstanceInfo _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^lNgKC+Z4(IMetadataDeclaration _0, Func`3 _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^+g+TCqVg(TypeDefDeclaration _0, Func`2 _1, Set`1 _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^fJqG(Func`2 _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeaverTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation).
```

I have understood that the autocad OEM dlls are somehow restricted compared to the dlls coming with the autocad installer.

What is going on? Why the postsharp tries to reflect the referenced dll in the project? Any suggestion how to fix the problem?

Comment: This seems like a bug that was fixed in PostSharp 5.0.39. Did you try to upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I should have know this but we also had some LispFunctions in the command classes and the **LispFunctionAttribute** Type is not available in the autocad OEM dlls.

```
[LispFunction("GetProperties")]
public static ResultBuffer GetProperties(ResultBuffer args) {
   ....
}
```

Excluding the methods from postsharp fixed the problem.

If it is possible would be good to show the Type name in the exception

> "PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: Cannot get the reflection
>   object for 'xxxxx.dll'"

Answer (score 1):

This issue can also occur if the assembly is present in the GAC and has not been removed before building. Significant changes such as method signature changes can screw with the PostSharp targets as it expects one signature from your source and finds a different one in the GAC.

Remove the assembly from your GAC folders to help eliminate this cause.

Comment: Yes, that's really the problem's source of error `Cannot get the reflection object for '<...file...>'. Build your project with detailed verbosity to see the assembly loading log. Also check that this project doesn't reference a project with a different processor architecture (x86/x64).` Thanks for this important note, which I found after hours! (Unfortunately, our application installs into the GAC.) By uninstalling the GAC application the build error was away. After reinstalling it was back again. Good to know this damn pitfall.

Comment: You can setup Pre-Build scripts to clear the GAC of your assemblies which can help tremendously with "house-keeping" your builds, you can also increment the build number on the version for the DLL to avoid this collision too.